# Spread Duration weighted OAS vs. Mkt Cap Weighted?

Tags: fixed-income, credit-risk, spread, duration

I am curious what the differences might be in rolling up OAS spreads across a portfolio by duration weighting vs. mkt cap weighting.

@Alex yes I meant S.D. weighted not Duration weighted